# What does it mean by: This might take a while?

Tags: grammar, linguistics, sociolinguistics, psycholinguistics, grammaticality

I googled that and I got to know its meaning as **This task will take a long time.**

Why is it so?
Cause **while** is used for short time period( what I know)...

Ex: let's sit here for a while.

So why is it not in the same way?

Comment: Look up *while* in a dictionary, come back and tell us what you found.

Comment: You are talking here of the noun "while". A "while" has a considerable number of senses in which it is used. If you look in a good dictionary you will find them quoted.

Comment: When we search the meaning of the word ' while', it says: a period of time(usually short)

Answer (score 2):

Whether "let's sit here for a while" is short or long is really anyone's guess.  It's not implicit in the phrase itself.  It could be two minutes or two hours.

That "this might take a while" means "...a while longer than you would probably otherwise expect" is just one of those things.  There's no real logic to it.

It reminds me of "that's okay" meaning "no, thank you," which seems to be counterintuitive to many non-native speakers.